# trying to show text from datatable in popup dialog

Tags: java, richfaces, spring-webflow

I have the following code, and i want to display any cells with, #{prop.toBeUpdated} set true,  contents in a popup me

```
<rich:extendedDataTable 
                rowKeyVar="rkv" 
                frozenColCount="1" 
                styleClass="dataTable"
                height="320px"
                id="sysPropList" 
                columnClasses="col" 
                selectionMode="single"
                value="#{sysPropsBackingBean.systemProperties}" 
                var="prop" 
                sortMode="single"
                rows="1000" 
                binding="#{dataTableScrollerBean.table}"
                selection="#{dataTableScrollerBean.selection}">    

                <rich:column id="attrCheckCol" 
                        sortable="false" selfSorted="false" width="40" 
                        label="#{messageSource.Select}">

                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="#{messageSource.Select}"/>
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="isUpdatedCheckbox"
                                 value="#{prop.toBeUpdated}" 
                                 title="#{messageSource.Select}"/> 

                </rich:column>

                <rich:column id="sysPropKeyCol" width="29%" sortable="false" sortBy="#{prop.propertyKey}" label="#{messageSource.SystemPropertyKey}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="#{messageSource.SystemPropertyKey}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{prop.propertyKey}" />
                </rich:column>

                <rich:column id="sysPropValueCol" width="32%" sortable="false" label="#{messageSource.SystemPropertyValue}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="#{messageSource.SystemPropertyValue}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:inputText value="#{prop.propertyValue}" id="sysPropValueInput" label="#{messageSource.SystemPropertyValue}" size="45" maxlength="255" onchange="updateSystemPropCheckbox(this, 'sysPropValueInput', 'isUpdatedCheckbox')"/>
                </rich:column>

                <rich:column id="sysPropDescriptionCol" width="32%" sortable="false" label="#{messageSource.SystemPropertyDesc}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="#{messageSource.SystemPropertyDesc}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:inputText value="#{prop.description}" id="sysPropDescriptionInput" size="45" maxlength="255" onchange="updateSystemPropCheckbox(this, 'sysPropDescriptionInput', 'isUpdatedCheckbox')"/>
                </rich:column>

             </rich:extendedDataTable> 

            <rich:spacer height="20px"/>

            <div id="sysPropsButtons" class="tabPanelActionButtons" style="text-align:center;">
                 <h:commandButton 
                    value="#{messageSource.Save}" 
                    immediate="false"
                    onclick="return false;"
                    reRender="systemPropertiesPanel">

                    <rich:componentControl for="saveSystemPropertiesButtonHitPanel" 
                            attachTo="sysPropsButtons" operation="show" event="onclick"/>
                </h:commandButton>
            </div>

            <!-- pop confirmation for removal of product -->
            <rich:modalPanel id="saveSystemPropertiesButtonHitPanel"
                resizeable="false" height="300" width="330">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{messageSource.ConfirmChanges}"/>
                </f:facet>

                <div class="exp-mpnl-dialog">
                    <h:outputText value="#{messageSource.ConfirmChangesText} 
<-- I WANT TO PUT THE CELL DATA HERE -->
"/>
                </div>

                <div id="propertiesConfirmButtons">  
                    <span><a4j:commandButton id="saveSysPropsButton" 
                     action="saveSystemPropertiesButtonHit"
                     onclick="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('saveSystemPropertiesButtonHitPanel');" 
                     value="#{messageSource.Save}" 
                     styleClass="action_button" 
                     rerender="errorPanel"
                     /></span>

                    <span><a4j:commandButton value="#{messageSource.Cancel}"
                            onclick="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('saveSystemPropertiesButtonHitPanel')"
                            styleClass="action_button"
                            ajaxSingle="true"/></span>
                </div>
            </rich:modalPanel>
```

Comment: You can implement mechanism similar to following example (using commandButton or commandLink): `<a4j:commandLink action="#{bean.setupTransactionDetails}" rendered="#{res.transactionType == 'Purchase'}" event="onclick" reRender="transactionDetails"  oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('transactionDetails')">
 <h:outputText value="#{res.transactionType}" />
 <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{res.transactionId}" 
target="#{chProfile.transactionId}" /> 
</a4j:commandLink>`, where transactionDetails is modal panel.

Comment: For regular data table you can use row selection for displaying modal, but I think it is not possible in you case.